# Chi-square plot to check for multivariate normality: Should I use the sample covariance or "normal" covariance?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, normality-assumption

I'd like to check if my observations are normally distributed by using a chi-square plot. To calculate the generalized squared distances (squared Mahalanobis distances) I need the covariance matrix of my observations.

Is it correct that I have to use the [sample covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_sample_covariance#Sample_covariance) instead of the "normal" covariance $$E[ (X - \bar{X})(Y - \bar{Y}) ]$$ in all cases where I don't know the actual E[X] / E[X] and have to estimate it with the respective mean?

Comment: If you don't know the covariance, presumably you would need to estimate it, yes. It won't actually be chi-square any more though.

Answer (score 1):

You can check MVN package of R and its web tool which includes chi-square plot to assess multivariate normality:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MVN/index.html

http://www.biosoft.hacettepe.edu.tr/MVN/

Comment: (+1). This solution has the advantage of being more generally applicable.